# Combine multiple rows with similar values in one column but different values on other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, group-by

I'm using SQL, trying to combine a table that looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Name  | Cherries | Pears | Apples |
+-----------------------------------+
| User1 |    Yes   |   No  |   No   |
+-----------------------------------+
| User1 |    No    |   No  |   Yes  |
+-----------------------------------+
| User2 |    No    |   Yes |   No   |
+-----------------------------------+
| User2 |    No    |   No  |   Yes  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Into a table that looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Name  | Cherries | Pears | Apples |
+-----------------------------------+
| User1 |    Yes   |   No  |   Yes  |
+-----------------------------------+
| User2 |    No    |   Yes |   Yes  |
+-----------------------------------+
```

I can use `GROUP BY` to group them by `Name` but I don't know how to deal with the other columns.

Comment: Put your `group by` query in the question so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: Pretty sure you just want `max`.

Comment: The general term for what you want is *aggregation*. When grouping you either have to `group by`or `aggregate`. Aggregation is some method of getting one value from multiple values i.e. `max/min/sum/avg` etc. If you need values from a specific row, then you would use a window function.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use aggregation:

```
select
    name,
    max(cherries) cherries,
    max(pears)    pears,
    max(apples)   apples
from mytable
group by name
```

This works because, string-wise, `'Yes'` is greater than `'No'`. So if both values are present in a group, `max()` gives `'Yes'`.